# typeahead.js only works with certain strings

Tags: javascript, python, django, typeahead.js

I have a Django project about movies (with Spanish titles) and I have implemented an autocomplete function with typeahead.js but it only seems to work with certain strings and I don't know why.

For example if I type "Los" theres a few movies that come up, but if I type "El" then none appear when they should. I know for a fact that it should work because the JSON that it receives has some results that should be shown.

Here is the JavaScript and Python code it uses:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var queryMovies = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        limit: 20,
        rateLimitWait: 800,
        remote: {url:'/get_movie/?q=%QUERY', wildcard: '%QUERY'}
    });

    queryMovies.initialize();

    $('#remote .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 2,
    },
    {
        name: 'queryMovies',
        display: 'value',
        source: queryMovies.ttAdapter(),
        templates: {
            empty: [
            '<div class="empty-message">',
            'No hay resultados con la consulta',
            '</div>'
            ].join('\n'),
            suggestion: function(data) {
              var url = "{% url 'movie' '00000' %}"
              url = url.replace('00000', data.id);
              return '<div><p><a href="' + url + '">' + data.title + '</a></p></div>';
            }
        }
    });
  });
</script>



def get_movie(request):
 results = []
 q = request.GET['q']
 movies = Movie.objects.filter(title__icontains = q)
 results = [ {'id': movie.id, 'title': movie.title} for movie in movies ]
 data = json.dumps(results)
 return HttpResponse(data, content_type = 'application/json')
```

I hope somebody can help.

Comment: Are you sure it is not just taking a while to return? The combination of 'el' can be very common and depending on if the 'contains' function you are using could be searching for any titles with 'e' and/or 'l' in them respectively.

Comment: It shouldn't take long because the database only has about 10 movies at the moment for testing and the example I explained above comes up instantly.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data?